# python win32clipboard not working for unicode characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have python script which send file paths to clipboard which I paste to a windows dialog box using pywinauto. 
Here is my part of code using win32clipboard:

```
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(paths,win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Script works fine for paths containing ASCII characters but if file names contains a unicode it gives ????? instead of unicode.What changes should I make to make it work.

Comment: It works for me, can you provide a fully functional code example?

Comment: like if paths="C:\Users\admin\Downloads\file\喵萌茶会字幕组][10月新番.exe" , then I am getting C:\Users\admin\Downloads\file\???????][10???.exe in a dialog box.

Comment: The string `u"喵萌茶会字幕组][10月新番.exe"` works for me too. How was that string read in your program? I'm assuming that either the type of paths isn't unicode or that it wasn't correctly encoded as such.

Comment: Can you post the code that sets the dialog box?

Comment: `u` tells Python 2 to treat the string as Unicode. In Python 3 you don't need `u` label before the string but it's not prohibited. Please find and read more detailed explanations about Unicode and encodings in Py2/Py3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code sample works for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import win32clipboard

def set_text(txt):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(txt, win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

set_text(u"喵萌茶会字幕组][10月新番.exe")
```

When I paste after this, I get exactly `喵萌茶会字幕组][10月新番.exe`

So the problem has probably to do with the contents of your string `paths`, either that it's not `<type 'unicode'>` or it wasn't correctly encoded in a previous step.

Comment: you are right.I corrected it now.Issue is with when using os.listdir to get file names .I missed to encode that.Thank you , it works now.