# Get file paths from the copied files in clipboard

Tags: python

How can I get all the paths from copied files in windows clipboard?

I tried this code, but it only returns one file path of what I copied, is there a way to get all the copied paths?

```
import win32clipboard

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
try:
    data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(49159).decode('utf-16')
except:
    data = 'No data'
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

print(data)
```

This all the available formats I get with `win32clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats()`

```
    49161: 'DataObject',
    49458: 'Shell IDList Array',
    49901: 'DataObjectAttributes',
    49902: 'DataObjectAttributesRequiringElevation',
    49459: 'Shell Object Offsets',
    49467: 'Preferred DropEffect',
    49483: 'AsyncFlag',
    49158: 'FileName',
    49240: 'FileContents',
    49159: 'FileNameW',
    49462: 'FileGroupDescriptorW',
    49171: 'Ole Private Data'
```

Comment: 49159 probably restricts what can be pulled out. Try with some of the other flags, or without any flag at all if the API permits that.

Comment: `FileGroupDescriptorW` seems to contain all the paths, but I can't decode it.

Comment: I get this with 'utf-16': 
`l耀 蜀″于ǘ떋偾于ǘඇ20210710_1127001.jpgl耀 㼀䑿ꐹǗ⶛㞣ꐹǗꡩ20210710_112902.jpg`
instead of: 
`F:\Photos\Inspiration\20210710_112902.jpg F:\Photos\Inspiration\20210710_1127001.jpg`

Comment: Then they are not actually UTF-16. `br'F:\Photos\Inspiration\20'.decode('utf-16')` produces
`'㩆停潨潴屳湉灳物瑡潩屮〲'` which doesn't exactly correspond with the text you posted, but seems like a plausible explanation of what's going on. Generally speaking, the vast majority of the Unicode BMP is Unihan, and so decoding random bytes as UTF-16 is somewhat likely to produce what looks like Chinese. We can't know which encoding your system is set up to use by default, but examining its settings will probably reveal this; or simply randomly guess that it's Windows code page 1252 and see what happens.

Comment: I tried all `encodings.aliases.aliases.keys()` to find the correct one, but they all return gibberish. This is what I get without decode method [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Rizw4jN5)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373874/python-win32clipboard-not-working-for-unicode-characters?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to decode the same thing. Finally figured it out! Hope it still helps you.

Note: I only cared about the filenames so I didn't bother decoding the other data, they should all be returning as char strings (bytes) because I wanted to have the right attribute count to match the way the struct is defined.

Some other useful links I referenced:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/1091137/Windows-Clipboard-Formats#_comments
- https://www.fluentpython.com/extra/parsing-binary-struct/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings  (in particular note 9)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/35cbf0a7-5d66-474e-b29a-df6b59cb62bd/not-receive-data-from-the-clipboard?forum=csharpgeneral  (this one was gave me some insight on how C++ devs think about the problem)

```py
    """
    given the following c++ stucts:
typedef struct _FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW {
      UINT            cItems;
      FILEDESCRIPTORW fgd[1];
    }
    typedef struct _FILEDESCRIPTORW {                               Actually because the unpacker will see many types as 1 count, we need to rely on s's 
      DWORD    dwFlags;                     uint        I           4s
      CLSID    clsid;                       16bytes     2d          16s
      SIZEL    sizel;               struct  2longs      2l          8s
      POINTL   pointl;                      2longs      2l          8s
      DWORD    dwFileAttributes;            uint        I           4s
      FILETIME ftCreationTime;              2dwords     2I          8s
      FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;                        2I          8s
      FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;                         2I          8s
      DWORD    nFileSizeHigh;                           I           4s
      DWORD    nFileSizeLow;                            I           4s
      WCHAR    cFileName[MAX_PATH];                     260*2s      520s    
    }
    """


    def unpack_filegroupdescriptorw(self, data):
        import struct

        cItems, = struct.unpack('<I', data[:4])
        print(f"cItems: {cItems}")
        fdw_fmt = '4s16s8s8s4s8s8s8s4s4s520s'
        fdw_size = struct.calcsize(fdw_fmt)
        print(f"fdw_fmt: {fdw_fmt}")
        print(f"fdw_size: {fdw_size}")
        fgd_data = data[4:4+fdw_size*cItems]
        print(f"fgd_data: {fgd_data}")
        fg_desc = struct.unpack('<' + fdw_fmt * cItems, fgd_data)
        print("here is the fg_desc unpacked into the various attributes:")
        print(fg_desc)
        print("...............")
        print(f"fg_desc is tuple of len: {len(fg_desc)}")
        subItemsPerItem = len(fg_desc)//cItems
        file_descriptors = []
        file_names = []
        for i in range(cItems):
            fd = {}
            fd['dwFlags'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem]
            fd['clsid'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+1]
            fd['sizel'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+2]
            fd['pointl'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+3]
            fd['dwFileAttributes'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+4]
            fd['ftCreationTime'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+5]
            fd['ftLastAccessTime'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+6]
            fd['ftLastWriteTime'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+7]
            fd['nFileSizeHigh'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+8]
            fd['nFileSizeLow'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+9]
            fd['cFileName'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+10]
            print('------')
            print(fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+10])
            print('=======')
            fd['cFileName'] = fg_desc[i*subItemsPerItem+10].decode('utf-16-le').rstrip('\x00')
            print(fd['cFileName'])
            file_descriptors.append(fd)
            file_names.append(fd['cFileName'])
        #print(f"file_descriptors: {file_descriptors}")
        print(f"file_names: {file_names}");
        return file_names
```

Comment: Your answer is clearly helping as it covers the hardest part of what is needed to answer the question (AFAICT) but it does not directly answer the original question. Please do the extra mile and update your answer to get the paths from copied files in windows clipboard. Also, your answer would be much nicer if it did not contain as many prints and contained a readily usable function or two (if you want to keep a generic unpack_filegroupdescriptorw function)